# Is this or ( || ) statement needed?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In the latest code [here](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) from underscore, on line 211, which reads

```
result || (result = iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
```

is the or statement needed?  Can it be replaced by

```
(result = iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker; // ?
```

`result` is initially set to false, and there is nowhere else in the code that is is modified except this one line.

Note that a JavaScript or (||) statement returns the first operand if it is truthy and the second operand if it ( 'it' being the first operand) is falsy.  This is directly from Crockford, the Good Parts.  Also noted that || does an or with truthy/falsy values not true/false values.

Here is the entire method reproduced from the link above:

```
var any = _.some = _.any = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    iterator || (iterator = _.identity);
    var result = false;
    if (obj == null) return result;
    if (nativeSome && obj.some === nativeSome) return obj.some(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (result || (result = iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
    });
    return !!result;
  };
```

Comment: Maybe it's for performance?

Comment: That function that contains the if runs multiple times and it works on the same value of result. It will only be false for sure the first time.

Comment: Result is false initially, but can be changed on each iteration. This code assumes that result will be changed only once. Without || iterator.call will be executed on each iteration.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo there are so many things already majorly wrong in this function if performance is a concern that doing such trickery for performance would be ridiculous.

Comment: @Ian just to clarify, `result` need only be a falsey value, not necessarily `false`

Comment: @MSost Sorry, you're right, that's what I meant. Too bad I deleted my comment because I keep confusing myself anyways

Comment: @Ian, the_web_situation well, you're right. I was not sure what breaker is.

Comment: @Tommi No problem, just trying to get to the bottom of this. Any observation is good here :)

Comment: This code is for when there is `Array.prototype.forEach` but not `Array.prototype.some`, however nobody has provided an example for when a browser implements the language this way ( not a user ).

Comment: ...hence there is no answer yet ...

Answer (score 7):

That makes me think the `result||` check is just in case... or to support environments where `forEach` is defined (e.g. via a shim), but `some` is not.

As pointed out in the comments, underscore's reliance on native looping methods (`forEach`, `map` and friends) doesn't seem to be a brilliant idea, for a few reasons:

- they are [slower](http://jsperf.com/for-foreach-jqeach) than simple loops
- you cannot break (well, you *could* with a dedicated exception, but underscore doesn't do that)
- `Array.prototype` can be tampered by other (malicious or silly) code

Comment: Oh! I never thought of that! When would `each` not be an `_` method? I guess I should look at the docs/code

Comment: This is something beyond my understanding, it is very easy to make custom each perform order of magnitude faster than the built-in one, yet underscore falls back to native which is not only much slower but has significantly different semantics too. Jesus Christ, WHY.

Comment: `each` is an underscore method with an alias to the native `forEach` if it exists

Comment: @the_web_situation underscore uses built-in `Array.prototype.forEach` if it's available (never mind that it has different semantics and slower speed than custom for each! :D)

Comment: @Esailija: your statement about custom forEach faster than native sounds intriguing - got any code to share?

Comment: @thg435 http://jsperf.com/for-foreach-jqeach A custom .each can be made perform just as fast as an inline for-loop. Note that firefox seems to have some hackery to completely skip using the built-in forEach in this perf test.

Comment: @the_web_situation `each` is a generic method - you can pass it an array or an object, so of course this check needs to be there

Comment: @the_web_situation I don't understand what you're getting so mad about. In any situation other than this one, you can "optimize" it like the answer you accepted. The fact that this is in the callback for `each()` means the `result ||` is **needed** because there's no guarantee that the `return breaker;` will actually do anything

Comment: @the_web_situation Look at [this line](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L79). It means if a native `forEach` exists, it is used. When that happens returning `breaker` won't stop anything. That answer is correct

Comment: @matehat Exactly. A situation without using the `each` method shouldn't need this extra check

Comment: @Esailija: interesting. I guess this comes down to how you call the fn: call() vs direct: http://jsperf.com/for-foreach-jqeach/2

Comment: @thg435 yes, the reflective call prohibits inlining so it will not be equal to for loop anymore. But not using context variable is the common case so you should use a loop that doesn't use `.call` unless it's necessary. The optimizations inlining provides are minimal in this example though, because it's an enabling optimization, the diference can be from 1-1000x, anything really.

Comment: @the_web_situation: if `forEach` exists, the `.some` exists too - so this code will actually never run with native forEach - see my edit. This `result ||` thing is for environments where `forEach` does exist (via a shim maybe), but `some` does not.

Comment: @thg435 That's not absolutely guaranteed because nothing technically prevents one from deleting `.some` and leaving `.forEach` as it is.

Comment: @Esailija: added some underscore bashing to the post ;)

Comment: change your answer then....`I guess the problem is with each - if it's native, there's no way to interrupt it (breaker won't work)`

Comment: @the_web_situation: changed to CW. Feel free to do what you want with it - it's yours.

Comment: @the_web_situation Your question was "Is this or ( || ) statement needed?". It is, but just as a defensive measure since underscore is a general purpose library and it needs to yield predictable outcomes, reliably. I don't understand what the issue is. Whether underscore uses `forEach` or not, and whether it is *performant* or not, is not relevant to your question.

Comment: This code is for when there is `Array.prototype.forEach` but not `Array.prototype.some`, however nobody has provided an example for when a browser implements the language this way ( not a user ).

Answer (score 3):

Answer is: **Yes**, it can be optimized in the suggested way **if it was native code**.

For understanding what would be going on let's simplify that code to what matters here, first:

```
var result = false;
for (var i in obj)
{
    if (result || (result = call(i)))
        return;
}
```

This means, that if either `result` already is non-false it'll return or if `call()` returns a non-false value it'll return. Since result is only changed by `call()`, the first check on `result` is redundant.

```
var result = false;
for (var i in obj)
{
    if (result = call(i))
        return;
}
```

This code will still return as soon as `call()` delivered a non-false value.

**Also since `each()` is a library function and OP returns `breaker` on a found item**

what really happens is:

```
var result = false;
for (var i in obj)
{
    if (result || (result = call(i)))
        break;
}
```

In which case the code can still be optimized in the suggested way as long as the librarys foreach function is used. The loop will be left upon a found value.

The confusing part is that `each()` is a library function and uses a function to simulate a loops body. Returning the library constant `breaker` from the body function will exit the loop.

As soon as `each()` decides to use the native `.forEach()` **the code cannot be optimized** anymore, since `.forEach()` will not understand the return value of `breaker`! See *thg435*'s answer for details!

Comment: But, according to [this line](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L83), returning `breaker` means the `each` function will stop iterating.

Comment: @matehat Thanks! Didn't notice that vertical scrollbar in OPs code, will edit.